# better solution than bumblebee?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, overheating

i am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS kernel 3.2.x

i was having overheating issues with the nvidia graphics card.

I installed the bumblebee project for a temporary solution. As a result i have to manually turn on the graphics support using optirun.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia

Is there a tweak to avoid heating and be able to use the graphics card like we do in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Bumblebee is the tweak.

NVIDIA have chosen to not support it, and so that's the best you're going to get for now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

**Turn off the graphics card from BIOS**
I am also using ubutnu 14.04LTS. Heating problem is almost all linux os has for those laptop having two graphics (integrated and dedicated like nvidia).

So,
**The solution is turn off the graphics card from BIOS setting.**
This works for me and gives almost 3.5 hours battery backup and no more heating.

Tell me if it works for U.